# I need help to start this exercise of propositional logic

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic

I have the definition of this function

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Subf : PROP & \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(PROP) \\
F & \mapsto Subf(F)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}with,
$Subf(F) = \{F\}$, $Subf(\neg F) =  \{ \neg F\} \cup Subf(F)$ and $Subf(F \circ G) =  \{F \circ G\} \cup Subf(F) \cup Subf(G)$

this function determines the set of sub-formulas of a given a propositional formula but i must show that if $F$ has $n$ connectives then $Subf(F)$ has at most $2n + 1$ propositional formulas.
I have no idea that how to start proof it. Any idea or hint?. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: yes, but I have no idea because I should apply the definition of the Subf function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction on the number of connectives in $F$.

If $F$ has $0$ connectives, then $F$ must be an atomic formula, so $Subf(F)=\{F\}$ by definition, which has $1=2(0)+1$ propositional formulas.

Suppose that for some $n$, for all propositional formulas $H$, that if $H$ has $n_0 \leq n$ connectives, then $|Subf(H)|\leq 2n_0+1$. Suppose $F$ has $n+1$ connectives. Then, since $n+1 \geq 1$, $F$ must be of the form $\neg F'$ for some $F'$, or of the form $F' \circ G$ for some $F'$ and $G$.

In the first case, since $F'$ has $n$ connectives, we can apply the induction hypothesis to arrive at $|Subf(F')| \leq 2n+1$, from which $Subf(F)=Subf(\neg F')=\{\neg F'\}\cup Subf(F')$ must have at most $1+(2n+1)=2n+2=2(n+1)<2(n+1)+1$ elements.

In the second case, suppose $F'$ has $m$ connectives and $G$ has $k$ connectives, with $m+k=n$. Then $F'$ has $m\leq n$ connectives and $G$ has $k\leq n$ connectives, so we can apply the induction hypothesis to arrive at $|Subf(F')|\leq 2m+1$ and $|Subf(G)| \leq 2k+1$, from which we have that $Subf(F)=Subf(F' \circ G) = \{F' \circ G\} \cup Subf(F') \cup Subf(G)$, so $|Subf(F)| \leq 1+(2m+1)+(2k+1) = 1+2(m+k+1)=2(n+1)+1$.

In both cases, we have shown that $F$ having $n+1$ connectives implies that $|Subf(F)|\leq 2(n+1)+1$, so by induction, it is true for all $n$.